# drupal linkedin integration module

Tags: drupal, linkedin-api

I am trying to get the drupal linkedin integration module working.  My configuration is:

Drupal 6.19
OAuth 6.x-2.02
linkedin module 6.x-1.x-dev

I have created my app on the linkedin developer network
I have added the correct keys to my linkedin module on my website
I have checked that all my URL's are correct
I have checked my permissions are correct

When I click on my account, edit linkedin, nothing happens.  Nothing is logged either.
I did the same with the twitter module and it worked fine.
I have uninstalled the linkedin and oauth modules numerous times to fix and it made no difference.

Anyone offer any pointers where to try next?

Answer (score 2):

fixed by reinstalling modules and prerequisites